# How and where can I overwrite the default string type?

Tags: delphi

I would like to make things straight and declare/overwrite the default `string` type to either a wide or an ansi string.

E.g. `string = WideString;` under Delphi 2009

How and where is it possible to declare/set/change the default string type, so the entire project and the IDE guarantees, it has been specifically overwritten?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where is the best place to declare/set this, so the entire project and
>   the IDE guarantees, that the default string is specifically
>   declared/overwritten?

Nowhere. `string` is keyword in Delphi and cannot be re-declared.

[Delphi keywords](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Reserved_Words)

In Unicode Delphi versions `string` is alias for `UnicodeString` and in earlier for `AnsiString`.

`WideString` is provided to be compatible with the `COM BSTR` type and it is not reference counted like `string`, `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString`

[String Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/String_Types_(Delphi))

---

No matter which Delphi version you use (pre-Unicode, or Unicode) using generic `string` type is preferred.

But in places where you need to be specific and code depends on exact type use `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString` even though they may map to generic `string` in particular Delphi versions.

- use `AnsiString` in pre-Unicode Delphi to ensure compatibility across versions and code correctness in code that depends on variable being `AnsiString`
- use `UnicodeString` in Unicode Delphi versions to future proof your code when code correctness depends on variable being `UnicodeString`

Comment: WideString is not reference counted?

Comment: No, it is not reference counted.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss But don't worry, the compiler emits the correct code to automatically free the string when it goes out of scope. The difference is almost always you generate a new copy of the original string when you assign, except when you pass in a method using const/var keywords.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Thank you for the extra info :)

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss if it were, then there wold be no point to introduce UnicodeString type. Like there is not Unicodehar and PUnicodeChar types.
The very existence of brand new UnicodeString type exactly means WideString was a different beast.

Comment: `No matter which Delphi version you` - just nitpicking, but in some Delphi versions depending on compiler options string could be also ShortString :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The yep, you are nitpicking ;-) I completely forgot about that one, but that compiler directive does not work in any Unicode Delphi version. I don't think it is really relevant at this point in time :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use Delphi 2009 or higher [`string` is defined as `UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/String_Types_(Delphi)). In earlier versions it is defined as `AnsiString`.

There is no way to redeclare the `string` type.

Comment: You **can** redeclare `string` type because it is not a keyword. It was a nice joke to insert somewhere in the project code the declaration like `type string = Integer;` and look at the reaction of programmer who trying to compile it ;) However it is a purpose to **not** redeclare base types.

Comment: Haha, thanks for pointing this out. I hope we wall know - without any explanation - that you should not do that ;-)

Comment: @Abelisto, Are you sure? Which Delphi version you refer to?

Comment: @kobik Delphi 7. I do not try to make such 'sabotation' on later versions.

Comment: Stop! Sorry for disinformation. It was `Integer = string`, not `string = Integer`. Because `string` is keyword and `Integer` is not. So you can not redeclare `string` at all instead of some macros if it present in modern Delphi.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. String is not WideString in D2009+. WideString is not ref-counted and exists in all Delphi versions to be compatible with windows bstr.

Comment: @Abelisto, hehe, I messed that part in my head, too. Now when I tried `type string = Integer;` it does not work anymore ;-)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You still can to make fun on your colleagues using `Integer = string;` ;) Have fun.